# retooling html template to php for mysql

Tags: php, html, pdo, execute

i have been trying to passing values from html template to php for several hours and have been unable to unlock my mistake. i've looked at the questions that may already have my answer. they come close but not quiet addressing my specific situation because i don't know if retrofitting the code side to the form is the problem. i begin with the php:

```
    try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=new_order", $username,                                            $password);  


    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database<br />';

    }catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>

    <body>


    <?php


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

    {
    $errors = [];
    }

    if(empty($errors)) {




// prepare sql and bind parameters
    $query = "INSERT INTO details (description, temple, quantity, price)
            VALUES (:description, :temple, :quantity, :price)";
    }
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':description', $_POST['description']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':temple', $_POST['temple']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':quantity', $_POST['quantity']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':price', $_POST['price']);
       $stmt->execute();

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;

    ?>


the html is the code i'm trying to retrofit to make work but i can't get beyond the error message from the php. 

here is the html form i am trying to retrofit. there are only four values that need be passed from html to php. it's hard for me to distinguish what is what with regard to the form fields already in place. i really need to know what i need to change to make this go. thanks, all. oh... here is the html:

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                <div class="page-header clearfix">
                    <h1><span class="thumb"><a href="javascript: void(0);"     title="Link to product page"><img src="img/331.jpg" width="123" height="91"     title="Product Image"></a></span>Framing You <small>Only xxxxxxxxxxxx</small><  /h1>
                </div>
            </header>
            <form id="shoppingCart" method="POST" class="form-inline" name="basket_form" action="myconnections/order.php">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="navbar">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <ul class="nav custom_nav">
                                <li class="pull-left">
                                    <div>
                                        <a href="http://xxxx.co" class="btn btn-info">
                                            <i class="icon-hand-left icon-white"></i>
                                            Continue Shopping
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                   <li class="pull-right">
    <a href="http://xxxx.co/checkout.html">
        <span class="btn btn-success continue_to_checkout" type="submit" value="Checkout" name="cont_to_checkout1">
            Continue To Checkout
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
                                <li class="pull-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                                <li class="pull-right">
                                    <div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger remove_all" type="submit" name="remove_all1" value="remove_all" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Be careful! All products will be entirely removed from the basket!">
                                            <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>
                                            Remove All
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="basket_list clearfix">
                        <div class="tables">
                          <table class="table table_header">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="2" class="description">
                                            Item Description
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="temple">
                                            Temple
                                        </th>

                                  <th class="quantity">
                                            Quantity
                                      </th>
                                        <th class="price">
                                            Price
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="subtotal">
                                            Subtotal
                  </th>
                                        <th>&nbsp;

                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                            <table class="table">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td class="thumb" rowspan="2"><a href="javascript: void(0);" title="Link to product page"><img src="img/331.jpg" alt="" width="123" height="91" title="Product Image"></a></td>
                                        <td class="description" rowspan="2">
                                            <a class="item-name" href="javascript: void(0);" title="Link to product page">The Carat</a>
                                            <div>
                                                <div class="item-availability"><em>These Diamond Shape Spectacles Accentuate Anyone's Style and Grace</em>.</div>
                                                <div class="item-sku">MDL331</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="size">
                                            <select class="span2" id="price" name="price">
                                                <option value="Buffalo Horn" selected>Buffalo Horn</option>
                                                <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
                                                <option value="Rose Gold">Rose Gold</option>
                                                <option value="White Gold">White Gold</option>
                                                <option value="Titanium">Titanium</option>
                                                <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
                                            </select> 
                                    </td>
                                        <td class="color">


                                            <input type="hidden" id="description" name="description" value="no">
                                        </td>
                                  <td class="quantity">Qty:                                 <input id="temple" name="temple" type="text" class="number" value="1" class="inline input-mini">
                                  </td>
                                        <td class="price">
                                            <span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">3000.00</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="subtotal">
                                            <span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">3000.00</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="remove">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" type="submit" name="prod2_remove1" value="remove_item" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Be careful! This item will be entirely removed from the basket!">
                                                <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning additional_empty">
                                        <td class="empty_td" colspan="8">

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                              </tbody>
                        </table>


                        <table class="table">
                              <tbody>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td class="thumb" rowspan="2">
                                      <a href="javascript: void(0);" title="Link to product page"><img src="img/332.JPG" width="123" height="91"></a></td>
                                        <td rowspan="2" class="description">
                                            <a class="item-name" href="javascript: void(0);" title="Link to product page">The Minimum</a>
                                            <div>
                                                <div class="item-availability">
                                                  <p><em>Timeless Design, </em><em>A true work of art</em>, <em>High Quality Lenses, </em><em>A Comfortable Fit</em></p>
</div>
                                                <div class="item-sku">MDL332</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="size">
                                          <select class="span2" id="price" name="price">
                                                <option value="Buffalo Horn" selected>Buffalo Horn</option>
                                                <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
                                                <option value="Rose Gold">Rose Gold</option>
                                                <option value="White Gold">White Gold</option>
                                                <option value="Titanium">Titanium</option>
                                                <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="color"><input type="hidden" id="description" name="description" value="no">
                                      </td>
                                  <td class="quantity">Qty:                                 <input id="temple" name="temple" type="text" class="number" value="1" class="inline input-mini">
                                  </td>
                                        <td class="price">
                                            <span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">4000.00</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="subtotal">
                                            <span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">4000.00</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="remove">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" type="submit" name="prod2_remove1" value="remove_item" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Be careful! This item will be entirely removed from the basket!">
                                                <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning additional_empty">
                                        <td class="empty_td" colspan="8">

                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                              </tbody>
                        </table>


                        <table class="table">
                          <tbody>
                                    <tr class="warning">
                                        <td class="thumb" rowspan="2">
                                            <a href="javascript: void(0);" title="Link to product page">
                                                <img src="img/333.jpg" width="123" height="91" title="Product Image">
                                            </a>
    </td>
                                        <td class="description" rowspan="2">
                                            <a class="item-name" href="javascript: void(0);" title="Link to product page">The Maximum</a>
                                            <div>
                                                <div class="item-availability"><em>Rimless frames</em>, <em> Sophistication &amp;  Elegance</em> by Design</div>
                                                <div class="item-sku">MDL333</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="size">
                                            <select class="span2" id="price" name="price">
                                                <option value="Buffalo Horn" selected>Buffalo Horn</option>
                                                <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
                                                <option value="Rose Gold">Rose Gold</option>
                                                <option value="White Gold">White Gold</option>
                                                <option value="Titanium">Titanium</option>
                                                <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="color"><input type="hidden" id="description" name="description" value="no">
                                      </td>
                                        <td class="quantity"><label class="inline">Qty:</label><input id="temple" name="temple" type="text" class="number" value="1" class="inline input-mini">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="price">
                                            <span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">5000.00</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="subtotal">
                                            <span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">5000.00</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="remove">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" type="submit" name="prod2_remove1" value="remove_item" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Be careful! This item will be entirely removed from the basket!">
                                                <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="warning additional_empty">
                                        <td class="empty_td" colspan="8">

                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                              </tbody>
                        </table>


                        <table class="table">
<tbody>
                                <tr class="warning">
                                  <td class="thumb" rowspan="2"><a href="javascript: void(0);" title="Link to product page"></a><img src="img/POV_clip_image001.jpg" width="111" height="87"></td>
                                  <td class="description" rowspan="2"><a class="item-name" href="javascript: void(0);" title="Link to product page">The Drop</a>
                                    <div>
                                      <div class="item-availability"><em>These Teardrop Cut Lenses with Lightweight Rimless frames are a work of art</em></div>
                                      <div class="item-sku">MDL334</div>
                                    </div></td>
                                  <td class="size"><select class="span2" id="prod2_size3" name="prod2_size3">
                                    <option value="Buffalo Horn" selected>Buffalo Horn</option>
                                    <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
                                    <option value="Rose Gold">Rose Gold</option>
                                    <option value="White Gold">White Gold</option>
                                    <option value="Titanium">Titanium</option>
                                    <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                  <td class="color"><input type="hidden" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="no"></td>
                                  <td class="quantity"><label class="inline">Qty:</label>
                                    <input id="temple" name="temple" type="text" class="number" value="1" class="inline input-mini"></td>
                                  <td class="price"><span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">6000.00</span></td>
                                  <td class="subtotal"><span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">6000.00</span></td>
                                  <td class="remove"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" type="submit" name="prod2_remove1" value="remove_item" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Be careful! This item will be entirely removed from the basket!"> <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> </button></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="warning additional_empty">
                                  <td class="empty_td" colspan="8"></td>
                                </tr>
                          </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="empty_basket">
                            Your Shopping Cart is empty!
                        </div>
                        <div class="order_blocks clearfix">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="span6 shipping_block clearfix">
                                    <div class="delivery_block pull-left">
                                        <h4>Delivery Method</h4>
                                        <label class="radio">
                                            <input type="radio" name="deliveryOption" id="deliveryOption1" value="0" checked>
                                            STANDARD - 4-5 working days: <span class="currency">$</span>0.00
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="radio">
                                            <input type="radio" name="deliveryOption" id="deliveryOption2" value="9.95">
                                            EXPRESS DELIVERY - 48h: <span class="currency">$</span>9.95
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="promotional_block pull-right">
                                        <h4>Promotional Code</h4>
                                        <div class="input-append">
                                            <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" name="promotional" value="" size="16" type="text" >
                                            <button class="btn" type="submit" formaction="demo_admin.html" id="promotionAdd" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="If you have a promotional code - you could add it here.">Add</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <h6>(Use any text here and you'll receive 10% of discount!)</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="span6 total_block">
                                    <h4>Summary Block</h4>
                                    <table id="basketTotalsList">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="total_position">Goods Subtotal</td>
                                                <td class="basket_subtotal">
                                                    <span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">325.67</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="total_position">Taxes (<span class="taxes_percent">0</span>%)</td>
                                                <td class="basket_taxes">
                                                    <span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">325.67</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="total_position">Delivery cost</td>
                                                <td class="basket_delivery">
                                                    <span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">325.67</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="total_position">Discount (<span class="discount_percent">0</span>%)</td>
                                                <td class="basket_discount">
                                                    -<span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">325.67</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="total">
                                                <td class="total_position">
                                                    <h3>Order Total</h3>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="basket_total">
                                                    <h3>
                                                        <span class="currency">$</span><span class="amount">325.67</span>
                                                    </h3>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <ul class="nav custom_nav">
                                <li class="pull-left">
                                    <div>
                                        <a href="http://xxxx.co" class="btn btn-info">
                                            <i class="icon-hand-left icon-white"></i>
                                            Continue Shopping
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="pull-right">
    <a href="http://xxxx.co/checkout.html">
        <span class="btn btn-success continue_to_checkout" type="submit" value="Checkout" name="cont_to_checkout1">
            Continue To Checkout
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
                                <li class="pull-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                                <li class="pull-right">
                                    <div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger remove_all" type="submit" name="remove_all2" value="remove_all" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Be careful! All products will be entirely removed from the basket!">
                                            <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>
                                            Remove All
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <footer>
                <div class="page-footer">
                    <p>&copy; xxxx xxxx 2015</p>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.shoppingCart.js"></script>

        <!-- show content -->
        <script>
            var el = document.getElementById("hideContentStyle");
            if (el) el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        </script>


    </body
```

>

i know that the templates has  prod2_color1, prod2_qty1, prod2_color3, prod2_size1 and prod2_size3 as the form fields. but i didn't think that this is an issue at this time because i get the error message Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'description' cannot be null'@ line 66.

i think i have quite a road ahead of me. thanks, yall.

Comment: do you getting any fatal error ?

Comment: Check MySQL table `details` and set the default value of the field `description` to NULL

Comment: this is the full error message:Connected to database

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'description' cannot be null' in /home/ewff/public_html/prac0.php:66 Stack trace: #0 /home/ewff/public_html/prac0.php(66): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/ewff/public_html/prac0.php on line 66.

Comment: Filter your post data and query. Take only that fields are not null.

Comment: this is line 66:        $stmt->execute();

Comment: wow....so much to learn. i think the last thing is to substitute the template field names with the my own (description, temple, quantity and price). but i am unable to identify which template fields i need to change. it's kinda murky in there. i thought i had it narrowed down but actually fouled it up and had to start over 3 times already. not looking for anyone to do my work but looking for a point in the right direction. i'll do the rest. thanks, y'all.

Comment: oh yeah....i almost forgot. the reason why i was getting the error message with regard to the php was that the pdo code was outside of the try/catch brackets. the exception didn't have a chance to run because it was initiated before the code had a chance to run. so i had to put _all_ the pdo code wthin the try{} catch() {}. repairing that fixed the fatal error message i had been receiving. thanks again.

Comment: i don't think i have it right. i'm kinda green to this stuff so would someone point me in the right direction? i thought i had the form fields correct on the code side but i was wrong. could someone please tell me which are the applicable field name? i have been trying to insert the names i want to be there (description, temple, quantity, price) so i can pass the values to php. can anyone help me get on the right track? thanks, yall.  i thought i had the right form field names but i was wrong. if anyone cares to consider my situation the url is: http://solutionm3.com/ordertest.html

Comment: it didn't work. rats. i tried to use the order form and then check phpmyadmin and saw nothing in the table. first thing i did was run my php script to see what type of response i'd get. i got this message: "Connected to database Array
(
)".
(although i don't know what is supposed to be in the array, errors perhaps? but it did take away the previous error message i was receiving regarding integrity error and  value need be set to null) in any event, the connection is there. next i made sure the string in the html code accessing the php script was correct and it is. where's the break in process?